# Trying to display different colors through bash script

Tags: bash, zsh

I'm new to scripting and have decided to learn with this homework that I gave myself.
The goal of this script is simply:

- display available colors in color
- pick a number to copy the hex color value of a colorscheme.

All the colors are displaying correctly except Black0~3 and Gray0.
Those 5 choices display in cyan and green instead. (please check screenshot)
Tried googling but to no avail. Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.
(I don't know if this info will be any helpful but OS: Linux, Terminal Emualtor: ST, Shell: zsh)

```
#!/bin/sh

# grab hex code
function fromhex() {
  hex=$1
  if [[ $hex == "#"* ]]; then
    hex=$(echo $1 | awk '{print substr($0,2)}')
  fi
  r=$(printf '0x%0.2s' "$hex")
  g=$(printf '0x%0.2s' ${hex#??})
  b=$(printf '0x%0.2s' ${hex#????})
  echo -e `printf "%03d" "$(((r<75?0:(r-35)/40)*6*6+(g<75?0:(g-35)/40)*6+(b<75?0:(b-35)/40)+16))"`
}

##################################################

# color values
Flamingo=$(fromhex "#F2CDCD")
Mauve=$(fromhex "#DDB6F2")
Pink=$(fromhex "#F5C2E7")
Maroon=$(fromhex "#E8A2AF")
Red=$(fromhex "#F28FAD")
Peach=$(fromhex "#F8BD96")
Yellow=$(fromhex "#FAE3B0")
Green=$(fromhex "#ABE9B3")
Teal=$(fromhex "#B5E8E0")
Blue=$(fromhex "#96CDFB")
Sky=$(fromhex "#89DCEB")
Black0=$(fromhex "#161320")
Black1=$(fromhex "#1A1826")
Black2=$(fromhex "#1E1E2E")
Black3=$(fromhex "#302D41")
Black4=$(fromhex "#575268")
Gray0=$(fromhex "#6E6C7E")
Gray1=$(fromhex "#988BA2")
Gray2=$(fromhex "#C3BAC6")
White=$(fromhex "#D9E0EE")
Lavender=$(fromhex "#C9CBFF")
Rosewater=$(fromhex "#F5E0DC")

##################################################

# display, select, copy hex color codes
echo -e "\nCatppuccin color selector"
echo
echo "[01] $(tput setaf $Flamingo)Flamingo #F2CDCD$(tput sgr0)     [12] $(tput setaf $Black0)Black0 #161320$(tput sgr0)"
echo "[02] $(tput setaf $Mauve)Mauve #DDB6F2 $(tput sgr0)       [13] $(tput setaf $Black1)Black1 #1A1826$(tput sgr0)"
echo "[03] $(tput setaf $Pink)Pink #F5C2E7$(tput sgr0)         [14] $(tput setaf $Black2)Black2 #1E1E2E$(tput sgr0)"
echo "[04] $(tput setaf $Maroon)Maroon #E8A2AF$(tput sgr0)       [15] $(tput setaf $Black3)Black3 #302D41$(tput sgr0)"
echo "[05] $(tput setaf $Red)Red #F28FAD $(tput sgr0)         [16] $(tput setaf $Black4)Black4 #575268$(tput sgr0)"
echo "[06] $(tput setaf $Peach)Peach #F8BD96$(tput sgr0)        [17] $(tput setaf $Gray0)Gray0 #6E6C7E$(tput sgr0)"
echo "[07] $(tput setaf $Yellow)Yellow #FAE3B0 $(tput sgr0)      [18] $(tput setaf $Gray1)Gray1 #988BA2$(tput sgr0)"
echo "[08] $(tput setaf $Green)Green #ABE9B3$(tput sgr0)        [019 $(tput setaf $Gray2)Gray2 #C3BAC6$(tput sgr0)"
echo "[09] $(tput setaf $Teal)Teal #B5E8E0$(tput sgr0)         [20] $(tput setaf $White)White #D9E0EE$(tput sgr0)"
echo "[10] $(tput setaf $Blue)Blue #96CDFB$(tput sgr0)         [21] $(tput setaf $Lavender)Lavender #C9CBFF$(tput sgr0)"
echo "[11] $(tput setaf $Sky)Sky #89DCEB$(tput sgr0)          [22] $(tput setaf $Rosewater)Rosewater #F5E0DC$(tput sgr0)"
echo
read -p "Pick number to copy hex code to clipboard [1~22]: " sel
  if [ $sel = 1 ] ; then
    echo "Copied $(tput setaf $Flamingo)Flamingo$(tput sgr0) to clipboard"
    echo "#F2CDCD" | xclip -sel clip
  elif [ $sel = 2 ] ; then
    echo "Copied $(tput setaf $Mauve)Mauve$(tput sgr0) to clipboard"
    echo "#DDB6F2" | xclip -sel clip
  elif [ $sel = 3 ] ; then
    echo "Copied $(tput setaf $Pink)Pink$(tput sgr0) to clipboard"
    echo "#F5C2E7" | xclip -sel clip
  elif [ $sel = 4 ] ; then
    echo "Copied $(tput setaf $Maroon)Maroon$(tput sgr0) to clipboard"
    echo "#E8A2AF" | xclip -sel clip
  elif [ $sel = 5 ] ; then
    echo "Copied $(tput setaf $Red)Red$(tput sgr0) to clipboard"
    echo "#F28FAD" | xclip -sel clip
  elif [ $sel = 6 ] ; then
    echo "Copied $(tput setaf $Peach)Peach$(tput sgr0) to clipboard"
    echo "#F8BD96" | xclip -sel clip
  elif [ $sel = 7 ] ; then
    echo "Copied $(tput setaf $Yellow)Yellow$(tput sgr0) to clipboard"
    echo "#FAE3B0" | xclip -sel clip
  elif [ $sel = 8 ] ; then
    echo "Copied $(tput setaf $Green)Green$(tput sgr0) to clipboard"
    echo "#ABE9B3" | xclip -sel clip
  elif [ $sel = 9 ] ; then
    echo "Copied $(tput setaf $Teal)Teal$(tput sgr0) to clipboard"
    echo "#B5E8E0" | xclip -sel clip
  elif [ $sel = 10 ] ; then
    echo "Copied $(tput setaf $Blue)Blue$(tput sgr0) to clipboard"
    echo "#96CDFB" | xclip -sel clip
  elif [ $sel = 11 ] ; then
    echo "Copied $(tput setaf $Sky)Sky$(tput sgr0) to clipboard"
    echo "#89DCEB" | xclip -sel clip
  elif [ $sel = 12 ] ; then
    echo "Copied $(tput setaf $Black0)Black 0$(tput sgr0) to clipboard"
    echo "#161320" | xclip -sel clip
  elif [ $sel = 13 ] ; then
    echo "Copied $(tput setaf $Black1)Black 1$(tput sgr0) to clipboard"
    echo "#1A1826" | xclip -sel clip
  elif [ $sel = 14 ] ; then
    echo "Copied $(tput setaf $Black2)Black 2$(tput sgr0) to clipboard"
    echo "#1E1E2E" | xclip -sel clip
  elif [ $sel = 15 ] ; then
    echo "Copied $(tput setaf $Black3)Black 3$(tput sgr0) to clipboard"
    echo "#302D41" | xclip -sel clip
  elif [ $sel = 16 ] ; then
    echo "Copied $(tput setaf $Black4)Black 4$(tput sgr0) to clipboard"
    echo "#575268" | xclip -sel clip
  elif [ $sel = 17 ] ; then
    echo "Copied $(tput setaf $Gray0)Gray 0$(tput sgr0) to clipboard"
    echo "#6E6C7E" | xclip -sel clip
  elif [ $sel = 18 ] ; then
    echo "Copied $(tput setaf $Gray1)Gray 1$(tput sgr0) to clipboard"
    echo "#988BA2" | xclip -sel clip
  elif [ $sel = 19 ] ; then
    echo "Copied $(tput setaf $Gray2)Gray 2$(tput sgr0) to clipboard"
    echo "#C3BAC6" | xclip -sel clip
  elif [ $sel = 20 ] ; then
    echo "Copied $(tput setaf $White)White$(tput sgr0) to clipboard"
    echo "#D9E0EE" | xclip -sel clip
  elif [ $sel = 21 ] ; then
    echo "Copied $(tput setaf $Lavender)Lavender$(tput sgr0) to clipboard"
    echo "#C9CBFF" | xclip -sel clip
  elif [ $sel = 22 ] ; then
    echo "Copied $(tput setaf $Rosewater)Rosewater$(tput sgr0) to clipboard"
    echo "#F5E0DC" | xclip -sel clip
  else
    echo "invalid choice"
fi
```

Here's a screenshot of what it looks like
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x0H2i.png)

Comment: Its a cool little script.

Comment: At least part of the problem is with the expression `$(((r<75?0:(r-35)/40)*6*6+(g<75?0:(g-35)/40)*6+(b<75?0:(b-35)/40)+16))`.  It maps numbers less than 75 (0x4B) to zero, and all the components of Black0 to Black3 are less than 75, so `fromhex` outputs `016` for all of them.

Comment: @pjh oooh! that part of the script I got from someone else's github.. Now I know where to edit. Thanks a ton!

Comment: You are tagging the question with `bash` and with `zsh`, but the script is neither bash nor zsh. Please make up your mind which scripting language you want to talk to, when asking a question.

Comment: my apologies.  it is my first post and i tried to be specific.. but i guess i was being specific the wrong way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this [gist](https://gist.github.com/dtmilano/4055d6df5b6e4ea87c5a72dc2d604193).

You can invoke it as

```
colors --256
```

[image: 1]

and check the values you want for black and gray and then make your mapping function return those.

Comment: this will be very useful. Thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using a modern terminal with truecolor support, you can use the hex colors directly:

```
function fromhex() {
  hex=${1#\#}
  r="0x${hex:0:2}"
  g="0x${hex:2:2}"
  b="0x${hex:4:2}"
  printf '\x1b[38;2;%d;%d;%dm' "$r" "$g" "$b"
}
```

and replace `$(tput setaf $<color>)` with `${<color>}` (`sed -E 's/\$\(tput setaf \$([^)]*)\)/${\1}/g`).

Comment: thank you for the info.  didn't know about truecolor support.
i tried replacing but i'm getting bad substitution error.. could you give me an example?
how would i replace this line
`echo "[01] $(tput setaf $Flamingo)Flamingo #F2CDCD$(tput sgr0)"`

Comment: It should be `echo "[01] ${Flamingo}Flamingo #F2CDCD$(tput sgr0)"`

Comment: perfect. now it works as i intended. thank you so much